# how do I get multiple resultset in Linq c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

```
var compobj = (from a in _db.FO_BA where a.BACode == vbacode select a);
foreach (var a in compobj)
{
    companycode = a.CompanyCode.ToString();
}
var emailobj = (from b in _db.EmailSentError where b.CompanyCode == companycode select b);
foreach(var b in emailobj)
{
    emails = b.Emails.ToString();
}
```

The emailobj return null, how do I get multiple resultset?

Thanks,

Comment: Are you looking for ObservableCollection of `emailobj`

Comment: kindly check in your DB if your value in `b.CompanyCode == companycode` condition returns a set. Your code seems fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var companycodeList= _db.FO_BA.Where(a=>a.BACode == vbacode)
                              .Select(x=>x.CompanyCode.ToString()).ToList();
var emailsList = _db.EmailSentError.Where(x=>companycodeList.Contains(x.CompanyCode))
                    .Select(y=>y.Emails.ToString()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get multiple email string, then you can try join in LINQ

```
var emailList = (from a in _db.FO_BA
                  join b in _db.EmailSentError 
                  on a.CompanyCode equals b.CompanyCode
                  where a.BACode == vbacode select b.Emails)
```